# Apache Superset - Unable to change Chart Source

Tags: apache-superset

I created some charts from csv file and sometimes I have to change dataset, but I got an error 'this.props.actions.setDatasource is not a function'.

**Work Flow**

Apache superset Version : latest

1. Choose one chart in "Charts" Menu
2. In chart customize UI, click image -> Change dataset

   [Pic1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn3Cw.png
3. Choose one another dataset

   [Pic2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XiEL.png
4. Click "PROCEED"

   [Pic3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmf2Z.png
5. I got a confirmation "succesfully changed dataset!", but chart source didn't change and also got an error 'this.props.actions.setDatasource is not a function'.

   [Pic4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kikTo.png

My best solution right now is to create a new chart with a new dataset!

Is there a known solution, why this keeps happening or can someone indicate what kind of error I have in my workflow?

Comment: I think this is a bug in their React environment, not your problem. Have you reported it to them via a support ticket or their bug tracker?

Comment: Ohh, okay!  I didn't report yet

Comment: Maybe this is also the same problem in their React environment.
I got an error, when I tried to edit chart on dashboard, "An error occurred while opening Explore"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/liGN9.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvyDJ.png